# How to read response header from upstream server in nginx

Tags: django, nginx, http-headers, reverse-proxy

I wanted to read the custom header and proxy the request to some gateway server.

**My configurations:**

```
location /route {

    proxy_set_header User $upstream_http_user;
    proxy_set_header Authorization "";

    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:3000/postdata/;
    proxy_method POST;

   }
```

**upstream server code:**

```
response = Response()
   response['User'] = str(user.username)
   response['X-Accel-Redirect']='/route'
   return response
```

Comment: `X-Accel-Redirect` is an internal redirect, so I am not sure if you can access upstream that time

Comment: what could be done?

Comment: other than X-Accel-Redirect?

Comment: What is the the use case you are trying to solve?

Comment: I want the request from client to be validated and upon adding the custom header from application server, the nginx should be able to redirect the request to some gate way server. This is what I need and seems